# Why the touch event is not functional?

Tags: javascript, cordova, dom-events

I have being trying to do an alert box to a touch event but I doesn't work. I have uploaded to Phonegap build and installed it in my phone but it does not recognise the touchstart events.

This is the code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box"></div>

        <div id="box2"></div>

        <div id="box3"></div>



        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script>
               $(document).one('deviceready', App.initialize());
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.css

```
#box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
#box2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;  
}

#box3 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

index.js

```
var App = {
    initialize: function() {
        alert("App initialized");
        this.clickEvents();
    },
    clickEvents: function() {
        $("#box").on('touchstart',function () {
            alert("Yellow box jQuery and touchstart event");
        });
        $("#box2").on('touchstart',function (){
             alert("Red box jQuery and touchstart event");
        });
        $("#box3").on('touchstart', function (){
             alert("Blue box jQuery and touchstart event");
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: did you get alert("App initialized")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
$(document).one('deviceready', App.initialize());
```

to

```
$(document).on('deviceready', App.initialize());
```

Comment: I've changed the method but It's not working neither

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late but...
You should be handing `App.initialize` as a callback argument:

```
$(document).on('deviceready', App.initialize);
```